# Autodesk Forge Heatmap Overlay

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am brand new to Forge and making my way through some documentation but it seems quite hard to get some of the older examples working (pages don't load correctly etc) and I am currently using version 6, which seems newer than many examples too.

Is it possible in client-side code to take in some user data and generate a heatmap (overlayed ontop of the floor of a house) based on that data (i.e. different blocks of colour, it can be quite rudimentary).

This is using a Revvitt model uploaded to Forge and shown in the Viewer.

I have no experience with Three.JS but if anyone could point me in the right direction, show me a working example, or at least tell me if its possible I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, with different levels of complexity:

You could use the official viewer APIs such as [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) and [clearThemingColors](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#clearthemingcolors-model) to add a semi-transparent color tint to selected *objects*.

If you need to overlay scene elements with anything more sophisticated, you could replace their original material with a custom [THREE.ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial). Just be sure to follow the documentation of three.js version 71 which is used by Forge Viewer. The process of adding new materials to Forge Viewer, and assigning them to specific objects is explained in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1. The article is a bit old, but I think the relevant parts of it (mainly the `createShaderMaterial` and `selectionHandler` functions) can be reused.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am very confused by all of this since I'm new to CAD and 3d graphics in general, but I will read through your links tomorrow and let you know if it has solved my answer.

Comment: if you are available for chat, to not spam this comment section, it would be amazing if I could just ping you a couple of questions on how exactly I determine what my objects are called in order to set color. I think that would be the best approach and a lot easier !

Comment: Check out my Autodesk University presentation ["Extend the Viewer"](https://autodeskuniversity.smarteventscloud.com/connect/search.ww?searchType=session&searchPhrase=extend+viewer#loadSearch-searchPhrase=extend%20viewer&searchType=session&tc=0&sortBy=relevance&p=). The 2nd extension explains how you can browse your scene, find specific objects, color them, etc. If you're still having questions, feel free to shoot us an email to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com. And if we can't help there, we can schedule a call.

Comment: sorry to be a pain Petr, and i really appreciate the help, I've sent an e-mail but would like to get as much done today if possible, and your link doesn't work for me? I have found a 6 page handout from that on the web doesn't seem to go into an example of locating an object in the model and specifically changing its colour :( I know I sound needy but a little more direction and I can get flowing :)

Comment: Sorry about the link, perhaps you need to be logged in to view the class info? Anyways, the slides basically describe a sample code that's already on github: https://github.com/petrbroz/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/extend-viewer. The actual piece of code that's coloring different scene elements is at https://github.com/petrbroz/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/extend-viewer/public/js/HeatmapExtension.js#L62.